# limited date for QUANDL API Requests

Tags: php, api, finance, quandl

I'm working on a personnal PHP app, trying to fetch stock market prices for Euronext shares with quandl api using an HTTP request

But the request returns only data until 2021-06-01.

PHP :

```
file_get_contents("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EURONEXT/ELIOR/data.json?start_date=2020-11-23&end_date=2023-05-14&api_key=[my_api_key]");
$parsed_json = json_decode($r);
```

But this request returns only data until 2021-06-01.

I'm afraid this API has been deprecated by quandl/nasdaq, is this the explanation?
If so, is there other API able to bring the same service?

Comment: Is there any metadata in the response packet? It's possible you've exceeded the maximum allowed page size and will have to paginate requests in order to get the next subset.

Comment: Changing the dates doesn't change the data range, and `start_date=2022-05-23&end_date=2023-05-14` gives absolutely no data. Contact Quandl to find out why they don't have data past 2021-06-01.

Comment: Return is a JSON file, in wich i don't see metadata.

Comment: yes i tried also with today date.

Comment: I will contact Quandl but it's not easy for me, as french it's difficult to write with those financial terms
Thanks to both of you